# Not getting prompt to set up superuser on Django's auth system?

Tags: django

I'm following a tutorial that uses Django's authentication system to log in users and when the sqlite3 db is first connected to django and the command `python manage.py syncdb` (tutorial is from before syncdb was deprecated) is run, I don't get this same message in the command line:

```
You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined. Would you like to create one now?
```

I instead ran

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

and this seemed to have set up the tables
but then when I run:

```
select * from auth_user;
```

nothing is returned to me in the command line.

How can I setup a superuser from command line and get encrypted password, etc?

Comment: `python manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: Perfect, thank you